# Создание таблиц с разными именами по запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо чтобы при переходе по ссылке, в БД создавалась новая таблица:

```
create table otchet ( 
id_user int (10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
email varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(15) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id_user) 
);
```

Проблема в том что при повторном создании таблицы, с таким же названием, sql естественно вернет предупреждение о том, что таблица с таким именем существует. Как сделать чтобы при каждом запросе, название таблицы изменялось. К примеру: otchet(1), otchet(2)...otchet(n);

Comment: По вопросу: можно тупо перебирать названия таблиц до тех пор пока таблица не создастся. Можно создать таблицу конфигурации, куда писать записанный номер таблицы и при следующем создании новой таблицы увеличивать счетчик. Но это не правильно, лучше сделать как в ответе говорят - создавать не новую таблицу, а новый отчет

Comment: У меня значения в отчет попадают только с базы. 
**P.S.** Использую библиотеку PHPExcel

Comment: Вы ни сколько не прояснили ситуацию ) И посмотрел на структуру таблицы - а где там отчет? Это логин/пароль пользователя. Вы хотите под каждого пользователя создавать свою таблицу? Зачем если можно использовать одну таблицы - создали ее, а данные добавляете уже в существующую таблицу

Comment: Я привел не все поля, так как мне только нужно понять смысл. И я ошибся, если я каждый раз буду создавать новую таблицу, то и скрипту нужно каждый раз ее указывать, а это геморой.

Comment: Легче сделать обновление таблицы, при каждом запросе, с использованием INSERT IGNORE или ALTER IGNORE TABLE, проиндексировав поля

Comment: Судя по всему вы делаете не то, что вам действительно надо. Пересмотрите используемый вами подход, изменение названия таблицы это не выход. Как вариант (который больше подходит для БД и может быть использован в вашей схеме) - создайте таблицу конфигурации и указывайте имя таблицы в ней. Хотя без самой задачи здесь трудно что либо предложить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать промежуточную таблицу с группой отчетов,а отчетам (все в одной таблице) добавить поле id_группы. Так будет правильней, чем создавать новые таблицы.

[Почитайте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/193136/)